# C# Is a Parallel foreach while loop possible?

Tags: c#, multithreading, input, parallel-processing

I'm not sure how the internal thread handling of Parallel.foreach works and whether it can guarantee that a construct like this would work?

```
Parallel.Foreach(Connections, c =>
    {
        Input in = c.getInput();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            object o = in.getNext();
            dosomething(o);
        }
    }
);
```

where in.hasNext() just waits for an object in the input stream and returns true. Basically can I run a bunch of infinite while loops in a parallel foreach structure whilst guaranteeing that they will all run at the same time.

(For the brave, can I adjust this so I can edit the connection list by adding (and removing, which should be trivial) connections and it will still read input from all connections in the list).

Comment: This should work, what happens when you try it?

Comment: I can try it but I can't guarantee it will never produce a race condition. Give me 15 minutes to set up a test server / client.

Comment: I assumed setting up a quick test server / client would be as easy & quick as it is in Java. C# isn't as nice.

Comment: if you're going to modify the Connections collection, you probably don't want to Parallel.Foreach and instead should just create and keep track of the Task instances yourself.  The Parallel.Foreach helper is more for when you need to do something parallel on a (static) set of items.

Comment: @Raynos: Really, you need to switch from blocking I/O to event-driven.  .NET Begin/End model for I/O calls use I/O completion ports underneath, which are much better than one thread per connection.

Comment: @BenVoigt this was back in the days when I didn't understand the joys of non-blocking IO ;). I can't go back to blocking IO these days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The number of threads using it is limited, so some elements will be processed one after another.
2. Editing lists while enumerating is not good. You will likely get an exception (depends on the list you're using
3. Why not start a new thread per connection?

Example code:

```
public ConnectionOpen(data)  
{  
    Connection conn=new ...  
    lock(Connections)  
    {  
         Connections.Add(conn);  
    }  

    new Thread(()=>  
    {  
        Receive(conn);//infinite loop goes here  
    }).Start();  
}  

public ConnectionClose(conn)  
{  
    bool removed=false;  
    lock(Connections)  
    {  
        removed=Connections.Remove(conn);  
    }  
    if(removed) conn.StopReceiving();  
}
```

Comment: I tried to format that code a little better, but for some reason the StackO parser was having trouble with it.

Comment: Sometimes development speed is required other than optimization of code (such as websites) and this section you gave me proved invaluable

Answer (score 0):

> Basically can I run a bunch of infinite while loops in a parallel foreach structure whilst guaranteeing that they will all run at the same time

No. Only a limited number of worker threads will be started concurrently, so if you run more infinite loops than there are threads, the last ones will never run...

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this code will work, but the precise number of threads running "simulataneously" will vary.

In addition to the parallel extensions, .NET 4 also added 'hill climbing'and thread injection to the thread pool, so basically the .NET threadpool will try adding threads to the Parallel.ForEach loop to see if more threads get completed, since yours will never complete the number of threads will vary, but I'm guessing will be non-ideal.

You might try using a ParallelWhile construct, the team has blogged about a couple ways to do this, [here is one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/08/12/9867246.aspx).

Comment: The parallel while loop runs the do block of the while in parallel.

I'm trying to get a parallel for loop with an infinite loop in the do block, so that each part of the for loop gets run even though the its an infinite loop

Comment: I don't think you will get this behaviour with Parallel.ForEach, it sounds like you're looking to have N threads run at the same time where N is large.

Why exactly do you need so many threads running at once?